# Cannot use my vga monitor?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics

So I just installed Ubuntu and my second monitor doesn't work. It shows up in the setting menu, even give the name, but my monitor itself is acting like it is turned off (orange instead of blue light and nothing on screen.) Its a vga monitor which I'm using a dvi adapter. Now, tbh, i've been considering getting rid of it soon anyway so if its the fact that is vga to dvi It wouldn't break my heart, but I would like to use it until I can get a new monitor.

Ryzen 5 1600

Radeon r9 380

8gb ram